# Remove specific category from URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

My custom structure permalink is set as shown below and category base is set to `.`

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

My current URL structure is this:

```
http://example.com/aaa/slug
http://example.com/bbb/slug
http://example.com/ccc/slug
http://example.com/xxx/slug
```

There are many categories and one of them is `xxx`. I want the URLs for this particular category to change from `http://example.com/xxx/slug` to `http://example.com/slug`

How do I go about doing this? I manage to get the URL the way I want but it's throwing me a 404 error.

Here's the code:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "xxx" ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $post->post_name .'-'. $post->ID .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    // This rule will will match the post id in %postname%-%post_id% struture
    $new_rules['^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)/?'] = 'index.php?p=$matches[2]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

I also tried this without success:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 ); 
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('init','flushRules'); 

function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
  $category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
  if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "xxx" )
  {
      $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/' . $post->post_name ) );
  }
  return $permalink;
}

function flushRules(){
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
  $newrules = array();
  $newrules['^/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
  return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

Edit: I tried with this too as per the comment but not working.

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the category for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "xxx" ) {
        $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'category_link', 'custom_category_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_category_permalink( $link, $cat_id ) {
    $slug = get_term_field( 'slug', $cat_id, 'category' );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $slug ) && 'xxx' === $slug ) {
        $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( '/', 'category' ) );
    }
    return $link;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '(?:/page/?([0-9]{1,})|)/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=xxx&paged=$matches[1]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=xxx&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );
}
```

Comment: check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296699/give-specific-category-its-own-permalink-structure/296703#296703, just remove the category name and it should do the job

Comment: I did that already but it's not working for my case. See my edit in the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is happening?

Comment: In place of `xxx`, I must add something like `a` else it just shows me 404 error. The URL is generated correctly which is `http://example.com/slug` but when I click on it, it shows me 404 error.